# Reinstalling a package after uninstalling it using adb shell uninstall with the k option

Tags: installation

I connected my Android device and used `adb shell` and while I intended to uninstall the stock music player app I instead uninstalled `com.android.providers.media` package using this command: `pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.providers.media`. Now I would like to reinstall it back.

I tried downloading and installing the apk file but got `INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE` error.

```
? .\adb.exe install com-android-providers-media-1580000075-39331427-4b5d0d066aef0e9e03a79b5dcd83005b.apk
adb: failed to install com-android-providers-media-1580000075-39331427-4b5d0d066aef0e9e03a79b5dcd83005b.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.android.providers.media signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]
```

So, what's the fastest and/or the easiest way to get it back? I guess because of using the k option (and from the error message I got while trying to install it from the apk file) that the package is already in the device and I can install it again easily.

--Update

I tried to completely uninstall the package but also that didn't work:

```
> adb uninstall com.android.providers.media
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
```

Comment: have you tried the -r option for reinstalling the apk?

Comment: I tried `adb install -r com_android_provider_media.apk` but got `INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE` error.

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi How should I type it? Is the way in my previous comment right?

Comment: yes it's correct. As this was saying that UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE that majorly because of the different signature used. Still try your luck using -d option, which allows to install a downgrade version.

Comment: push package(s) to the device and install them with following options.
     -l: forward lock application
     -r: replace existing application
     -t: allow test packages
     -s: install application on sdcard
     -d: allow version code downgrade (debuggable packages only)
     -p: partial application install (install-multiple only)
     -g: grant all runtime permissions